# Give back money algorithm

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I have to solve this problem in my app : the seller have a wallet of all the monney he have in a HashMap (for value and quantity).

For example :

- <5000, 18> for 18 tickets of 50 euros
- <1000, 2> for 2 tickets of 10 euros
- <500, 1> for 2 tickets of 5 euros
- <200, 5> for 5 coins of 2 euros
- <10, 3> for 3 coins of 10 cents
- *...*

A user pay something to the seller and the vendor have to get back money if the count is not good. I have to make an algorithm giving the minimum of coins to get the exact same value (in an hashmap).

For example I have to give back **26 euros** so I have to give 2 tickets of 10 euros and 3 coins of 2 euros and the return hashmap have to be like this :

- <1000, 2>
- <200, 3>

This is the problem because if the algorithm take the first elements without knowing if it's possible to have the right account it would give 2 tickets of 10 euros, then after 1 ticket of 5 and after it's blocked because giving 2 euros more give you a sum of 27.

How can I do to have the good algorithm ?

I try this :

```
for ((value, quantity) in my_wallet_map){
      var q = quantity
      while (q > 0){
          if (!isPossibleToPayFromBelow(value, amount, my_wallet_map)){
          what_to_pay_map[value] = (what_to_pay_map[value] ?: 0.toLong()) + 1.toLong()
          my_wallet_map[value] = (my_wallet_map[value] ?: 0.toLong()) - 1.toLong()
          amount -= value
          }
          if (calculTotalFromHashMapInLong(what_to_pay_map) == amount_no_modified)
            break
          q -= 1.toLong()
          }
          if (calculTotalFromHashMapInLong(what_to_pay_map) == amount_no_modified)
                break
}
```

Using the functions :

```
  fun calculTotalFromHashMapInLong(map: HashMap<Long, Long>): Long{
      var total: Long = 0
      for ((value, quantity) in map)
          total += value * quantity
      return total
  }


  fun isPossibleToPayFromBelow(v: Long, t: Long, map: SortedMap<Long, Long>): Boolean{
      val new_map = map.toSortedMap(reverseOrder())

      var total: Long = 0.toLong()

      for ((value, quantity) in new_map){
          if (quantity != 0.toLong() && value < v) {
              total += (value * quantity)
          }
      }
      return total > t
  }
```

But the result is not good at all. I try a lot of things.

Comment: I guess you can try to adapt [coin change problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/). Also, maybe [this lecture](http://ace.cs.ohiou.edu/~razvan/courses/cs4040/lecture19.pdf) will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no perfect and fast solution for this.
However, you can try a greedy algorithm first, and if it fails, you can try an exact algorithm (which can be really slow unfortunately).

I'm sorry but I don't know Kotlin very well, but as you asked for an algorithm only, I wrote it in Python with the least pythonics things possible, so that you can convert it easily to Kotlin.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""Give back money algorithm."""

DEBUG = True

def print_debug(msg):
    """Prints if DEBUG is set to True."""
    if DEBUG:
        print("    --> {}".format(msg))

# Works great with a structure
# cash_list = [[value_of_coin_1, number_of_coins_1],
#              [value_of_coin_2, number_of_coins_2],
#              ...]
# sorted desc. on value
def greedy(cash_list, value):
    """Tries to gather the requested sum by taking each time the largest
    "coins" avaible."""
    give_cash_list = []
    for (v, n) in cash_list:
        n_of_v = min(n, value // v)
        give_cash_list.append([v, n_of_v])
        value -= v * n_of_v
        if value == 0:
            return give_cash_list
    return None

def exact(cash_list, value):
    """Examines all the possible ways to gather the requested sum."""
    pre_solution_pool = [[[], 0]]
    final_solution_pool = []
    for (v, n) in cash_list:
        new_pre_solution_pool = []
        for (p_s, p_v) in pre_solution_pool:
            new_pre_solution_pool.append([p_s, p_v])  # 0 of the new coin
            for j in range(1, min(n, (value - p_v) // v) + 1):
                new_pre_solution = [p_s + [[v, j]], p_v + v * j]
                if new_pre_solution[1] == value:
                    final_solution_pool.append(new_pre_solution[0])
                else:
                    new_pre_solution_pool.append(new_pre_solution)
        pre_solution_pool = new_pre_solution_pool
    return final_solution_pool

def nb_of_coins(solution):
    """Returns the number of coins of a solution."""
    return sum([n for v, n in solution])

def best_exact(final_solution_pool):
    """Returns the best solution from the exact algorithm."""
    if final_solution_pool:
        return sorted(final_solution_pool, key=nb_of_coins)[0]
    else:
        return None

def compute_new_cash_list(cash_list, give_cash_list):
    """Returns the new cash_list where coins of give_cash_list have been
    removed."""
    new_cash_list = []
    (m, n) = (len(cash_list), len(give_cash_list))
    (i, j) = (0, 0)
    while i < m and j < n:
        (a, b) = cash_list[i]
        (c, d) = give_cash_list[j]
        if a == c:
            new_cash_list.append([a, b - d])
            i += 1
            j += 1
        else:
            new_cash_list.append([a, b])
            i += 1
    return new_cash_list

def give_back(cash_list, value):
    """Best of the two worlds."""
    g = greedy(cash_list, value)
    if g is not None:
        return g, compute_new_cash_list(cash_list, g)
    print_debug("Greedy failed for {} : {}".format(cash_list, value))
    e = best_exact(exact(cash_list, value))
    if e is not None:
        return e, compute_new_cash_list(cash_list, e)
    print_debug("Exact failed for {} : {}".format(cash_list, value))
    return None, cash_list

def main():
    """Launcher."""
    my_cash_list = [[5000, 18], [1000, 2], [500, 1], [200, 5], [10, 3]]
    my_value = 2600
    print(give_back(my_cash_list, my_value))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I hope that it helps. Feel free to ask any questions!

Answer (score 1):

## Problems with the greedy algorithm

Imagine you have the following notes

```
|-----|------|
|count|value |
|-----|------|
|    1|20.00 |
|    2|10.00 |
|    3| 5.00 |
|    3| 2.00 |
|-----|------|
```

And you want to get 21.00 then the greedy algorithm takes a 20 and gets stuck. In this case, you have to try all the combinations.

## Alternative solution

The brute force method can work, assuming there are not too many coins in the pouch, otherwise the combinations to try gets very large very quickly.

```
// Sorting the map forces an order
val money = mapOf(
        5000 to 18,
        1000 to 2,
        500 to 1,
        200 to 5,
        10 to 3
).toSortedMap()

// The target amount to find a way of making
val target = 2600

val options = money.asSequence().fold(listOf(listOf<Int>())) { acc, (value, count) ->
    // For each denomination add all the possible counts
    acc.flatMap { option -> (0..count).map { amount -> option + amount } }
}.map { it.zip(money.keys) }

val result = options
    // Only use the counts that give the right change
    .filter { it.map { (a, b) -> a * b }.sum() == target }
    // Find the least amount of notes
    .minBy { it.map { it.first }.sum() }

if (result == null) {
    println("Can't make the change")
} else {
    println(result)
}
```

### Possible optimisations

You could limit the options, so that only the ones <= target are created, I didn't do this to keep the code short, and as for the numbers you provided the full set of combinations are still small.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple dynamic programming algorithm to find the minimum number of coins required to generate the change.

```
val coins=listOf(1,2,5,10)

tailrec fun change(target: Int): Int = when (target){
    0 -> 0
    else -> coins.filter{ it <= target}.map { change(target-it) + 1 }.min()!!
}
```

Comment: Just realized that this doesn't scale for large numbers.  I'll work on a better solution.